# Transporting Sparse Matrix from Python to R

Tags: python, r, sparse-matrix, text-analysis

I am doing some text analysis work in Python. Unfortunately, I need to switch to R  in order to use a particular package (unfortunately, the package cannot be replicated in Python easily).

Currently the text is parsed into bigram counts, reduced to a vocabulary of about 11,000 bigrams, and then stored as a dictionary:

```
{id1: {'bigrams':[(bigram1, count), (bigram2, count), ...]},
id2: {'bigrams': ...}
```

I need to get this into a dgCMatrix in R, where the rows are id1, id2, ... and the columns are the different bigrams such that a cell represents the 'count' for that id-bigram.

Any suggestions? I thought about expanding it just to a massive CSV, but that seems super inefficient plus probably infeasible due to memory constraints.

Comment: An example with actual values and in greater numbers might be more useful. As it is you are expecting us to do quite a bit of work before even attempting to code. Maybe you fancy Python coders grasp this layout better than this feeble R-coder, but can you please provide more substance?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Could you could write out the matrix in MatrixMarket format using [scipy](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/tutorial/io.html) [mmwrite](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.io.mmwrite.html#scipy.io.mmwrite) and then read it into R using [readMM](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/Matrix/html/externalFormats.html) from the [Matrix](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/Matrix/index.html) package?

Comment: This worked! It isn't a super memory efficient way of doing it (as far as I can tell), but managed to get it to run on my computer just fine.

Comment: Hopefully it's pretty time efficient! LOL! :) Glad I could help.